# "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." in Smart Device Projects VS2008

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2008, smart-device

I am new to Smart Device Projects. I installed MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4. And i add MySql.Data.CF for mysql connection in vs 2008.

But i can't get the output. ***"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."*** exception through on the connection.open().

```
server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;Persist Security Info=True;database=mcubic
```

its a working Connection string. So database server user id, password are correct. No issue in that. But i can't understand why it through error on Smart Device Projects only.

The code given below.

```
try
 {
    string connectionString = "server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;Persist Security Info=True;database=mcubic";
    string query = "select b.Outlet_Master_Name from mcs_user_outlet a,outlet_master b where a.Mcs_User_Outlet_User_Id=3 and a.Mcs_User_Outlet_Outlet_Id = b.Outlet_Master_Id";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();
 }
catch(Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(""+ex.Message);
}
```

Help me to find out the error.

I have tried below Connection Strings.

```
server=192.168.1.100;UID=mcubic;Persist Security Info=True;database=mcubic

server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;Persist Security Info=False;database=mcubic

server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=mcubic;

server=192.168.1.100;UID=mcubic;Persist Security Info=True;database=mcubic;pooling = false;
```

But No Use.

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: No Sir, What is the Need for that?. Now i try it sir. But Same error repeat.

Comment: Aren't you missing a password field from the connection string?

Comment: I have tried "server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=mcubic;pooling=False"; Also Sir,. But no use. Any Special Connection String for Smart Devices

Comment: Hi @Sagotharan, do you know what port your database server is running on? Is it the default 3306? You can specify this in the connection string by appending ;port=xxxx on the end of your connection string. Also make sure the MySql server is running!

Comment: In Windows Application This Code is worked Correctly. But in Smart Devices it not work. Anyway i tried "server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=mcubic;port=3306"; Connection String Also.

Comment: If you restart MySql does it help? Just make sure it's not a state issue. If you downgrade to connector 6.3.8 does that make a difference? I checked and that is the version we are using.

Comment: Also, use the simplest connection string possible: Server=192.168.1.100;Port=3309;Database=Test;Uid=mcubic;Pwd=mcs@2011$; (don't include the persist security info section)

Comment: I am using MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4. I can't find why this repeating. I will try and tell mr.dash. Thank you very much to support me.

Comment: Is this a compiled application or is it running in VS emulator?

Comment: No I have Close the emulator when the programs finished. The first execution itself this problem repeats.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem. Hope this helps you too. Code below is working perfectly for me.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=server-ip;database=db-name;Character Set=utf8;Uid=user-name;password=****;");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from table-name", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    conn.Open();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    conn.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. You are vary Great. Thanks. I will try this my off time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem may be due to the way in which Smart Devices connect to external networks. I take it that you're trying to run this from Visual Studio using an emulator.

I gather that you need to connect to the external network on which your MySql server resides before attempting to connect to the server itself.

There's an [article here](http://techyard.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/visual-studio-2008-smart-device-project-connect-to-sql-server/) that covers your problem but with SQL Server. I'm sure that it would cover the same problem that your experiencing.